# Jmeter JSON Format Post Processor breaks Token retrieval

Tags: json, jmeter, access-token, jmeter-plugins

I am working with Jmeter and i want to format the JSON results. So i installed  JSON Format Post Processor and added it to the root of the project.

It works correctly, it formats the JSon response for easy readability. However there is also a request with requires Token authentication. It does not work with the  JSON Format Post Processor.

Example:

Correct coin retrieval without JSON Format Post Processor:

```
{"access_token":"Secret","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

And with:

```
{
    "access_token": "Secret",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

I use a regulair extractor to extract the token: `access_token":"([a-zA-Z0-9.\-\_]*)`

This seems to break in combination with the formatter. No valid token access is denied in all requests

Is there an easy way around this? It seems i can either use Jmeter JSON Format Post Processor for my complete project, or not at all.

Anyone know how i deal with this?

Comment: You might have to read the value as a string.
In the previous mode, you are applying an regex on a string.
In the 2nd, you have an object. and you need to read the "acces_token" key.
try reading it first, only then apply the regex.
prev.get("access_token):"([a-zA-Z0-9.\-\_]*)

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, any feedback on answer? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, apply JSON Format Post Processor **after** regex extractor. This could help.
For easier access to data in JSON format you can use [JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=JSONPathExtractor) or [SmartMeter](https://www.smartmeter.io/)'s [Boundary Body Extractor](https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation?utm_source=smartmeter&utm_medium=tool#toc-et-sm---boundary-body-extractor)

Comment: I have tried all 3 awnsers non worked. I tried changing to access_token":"([^"]+?)" and Template change to $2$ as well as changing the place of the post processor to after the token retrieval.

Comment: Have you tried JSON Path extractor or Boundary Body Extractor mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

To extract JSON data the best option is native JSON Extractor:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor

Regarding your precise issue, a better regexp would be:

> access_token":"([^"]+?)"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have optional white space after `:`

Regular expression:

`access_token":(\s*)"([a-zA-Z0-9.\-\_]*)`

Template change to use `$2$`