# Get and set access token through Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new in JMeter. I am trying to set access token dynamically through "Regular Expression Extractor". 
Basically I am trying to first login and then from it's response , I am trying to get access token and set it in "CreatePost" API.

I am able to get access token using #1 Login API where response is as below.

> {
>       "Message": "Login successfully.",
>       "Status": "Success",
>       "HttpStatus": 200,
>       "Data": {
>           "token_type": "Bearer",
>           "expires_in": 10000,
>           "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiE",
>           "refresh_token": "2bcf1f455f2",
>           "name": "jmeter_test",
>           }
>   }

Could you please help me to get access_token from above response. 
To get this , I have created "Regular Expression Extractor " and set

```
Name of Createdvariable :  access_token,
Regular Expression:        "access_token": "value"
Template                   $1$
Match No.                  1
```

Could yo please check the regular expression?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670768/jmeter-json-format-post-processor-breaks-token-retrieval/45676310?r=SearchResults#45676310 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670768/jmeter-json-format-post-processor-breaks-token-retrieval/45676310?r=SearchResults#45676310

Comment: Use JSON Path PostProcessor as expression: $.access_token OR $..access_token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to use the regular expression extractor you need to amend your regular expression to look like:

```
"access_token":\s+"(\w+)"
```

where:

- `(\w+)` matches any number of aplhanumeric characters
- `\s+` matches optional whitespace character

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

---

However for [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) responses it makes sense to use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which allows executing arbitrary [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries to get "interesting" data from the JSON responses, the relevant JsonPath expression will be:

```
$..access_token
```

where:

- `..` is ["deep scan" operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators), it will find the search term anywhere in the data
- `access_token` - the JSON attribute you're looking for

[image]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/)

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON Extractor as a child of the Sampler Returning Response with following JSON Path Expression:

> $.Data.access_token

[image]

[image]